# c# unity get data from Elasticsearch Restful API

Tags: elasticsearch, 3d, rest

I am new to Elasticsearch. What I need to do now is send a specific query to the DB and receive the result from Unity via the rest of the API.

maybe [unity] ---query--> [DB] ---data--> [restful API] ---> [unity] this is I want it program

I make unity navigator IoT...

I want the Unity navmesh agent to move (e.g. coordinates x, y, z) by receiving data from Elasticsearch once every 3 seconds. get request is http:localhost:9200/location/_search?q=x:6.7 this URL result just 1 data but  It contains headers, so I don't know how to do it.

1. elasticsearch send data term 3seconds possible?
2. how to get data only result no include header

somebody help me.....  ㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠ

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. You can send a GET request to your DB endpoint, and append your query to the end of the url.

```
https://xxxxx.northamerica-northeast1.gcp.elastic-cloud.com:xxxx/xxxx/_search?&size=1&sort=timestamp:desc
```

The above query returns me the latest entry in my xxxx cluster.

Once you get the data you wanted, you can use JSON deserialization to deserialize them into your customized object. You are then able to use anything you want without the header.

To get data once per 3 seconds you can use a coroutine to send the GET request every 3 seconds.